# How to PHP MySQL query a STRING?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a string called $searchquery. $searchquery contains this SQL command:

```
SELECT * FROM `videos` WHERE (`Title` LIKE "%query%" OR `Tags` LIKE "%query%")
```

How can I make MySQL execute this command from a PHP page then display the results on PHP page??

I have tried

```
$sql = ($searchquery)
```

But dosent seem to work?

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Querying the database requires a connection to the database. This is PHP/MySQL 101 and is covered by literally hundreds (if not thousands) of tutorials.

Comment: `mysqli_query` read http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: Have you tried to resolve this yourself before posting? If so, what was it? Edit: ah yes, this one https://stackoverflow.com/q/47250457/1415724 and that failed you.

Comment: [Connect to your database](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php#refsect1-pdo.construct-examples), then [execute the query](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php#refsect1-pdostatement.execute-examples)
.

Comment: The string is populated as the code executes, thats why I couldnt just do $sql = "select blah blah". Raymond's answer is what I was looking for thanks

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you need to create database connection

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost"; 
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "test";

    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

// then execute your query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `videos` WHERE (`Title` LIKE '%query%' OR `Tags` LIKE '%query%')";
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

// and fetch result set 
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   print_r($row);
}
?>
```